# How to multiply two created series to create third series

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, lambda

I have created two series and I want to create a third series by doing element-wise multiplication of first two. My code is given below:

```
new_samples = 10 # Number of samples in series
a = pd.Series([list(map(lambda x:x,np.linspace(2,2,new_samples)))],index=['Current'])
b = pd.Series([list(map(lambda x:x,np.linspace(10,0,new_samples)))],index=['Voltage'])
c = pd.Series([x*y for x,y in zip(a.tolist(),b.tolist())],index=['Power'])
```

My output is:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

To keep things clear, I am pasting my actual `for` loop code below. My data frame already has three columns `Current`,`Voltage`,`Power`. For my requirement, I have to add new list of values to existing columns `Voltage`,`Current`. But,  `Power` values are created by multiplying already created values. My code is given below:

```
for i,j in zip(IV_start_index,IV_start_index[1:]):            
    isc_act = module_allData_df['Current'].iloc[i:j-1].max()
    isc_indx = module_allData_df['Current'].iloc[i:j-1].idxmax()
    sample_count = int((j-i)/(module_allData_df['Voltage'].iloc[i]-module_allData_df['Voltage'].iloc[j-1]))
    new_samples = int(sample_count * (module_allData_df['Voltage'].iloc[isc_indx]))
    missing_current = pd.Series([list(map(lambda x:x,np.linspace(isc_act,isc_act,new_samples)))],index=['Current'])
    missing_voltage = pd.Series([list(map(lambda x:x,np.linspace(module_allData_df['Voltage'].iloc[isc_indx],0,new_samples)))],index=['Voltage'])
    print(missing_current.tolist()*missing_voltage.tolist())
```

Sample data: module_allData_df.head()

```
     Voltage  Current    Power  
0  33.009998   -0.004 -0.13204  
1  33.009998    0.005  0.16505  
2  32.970001    0.046  1.51662  
3  32.950001    0.087  2.86665  
4  32.919998    0.128  4.21376
```

sample data: module_allData_df.iloc[120:126] and you require this also

```
       Voltage  Current    Power  
120   0.980000    5.449  5.34002  
121   0.920000    5.449  5.01308  
122   0.860000    5.449  4.68614  
123   0.790000    5.449  4.30471  
124  33.110001   -0.004 -0.13244  
125  33.110001    0.005  0.16555
```

sample data: IV_start_index[:5]

```
[0, 124, 251, 381, 512]
```

Based on `@jezrael` answer, I have successfully created three separate series. How to append them to main dataframe. My requirement is explained in following plot. [image]

Comment: What is the point of the `list(map(lambda x: x, ...)))`?

Comment: and ``a.tolist()`` returns you a list of list like [[....]], maybe you want to do is ``a.tolist()[0]``

Comment: Above code is present inside a `for` loop. Here, the limits keep changing for each iteration. Hence, I create new set of series for each iteration. In above code, I have given values `(2,2,new_samples)` and `(10,0,new_samples)` of a particular iteration.

Comment: Your series `a` and `b` contain only one entry and the entry is a list of 10 elements, is that what you want?

Comment: Why are you mapping to lambda?

Comment: @bigbounty, why I am mapping to lambda? I just thought it this way from my understanding of python in past one month.

Comment: Lambda is used for anonymous functions. Ur requirement can be done using numpy arrays and numpy arrays are fast. Or just without mapping with list you can multiply them

Comment: @Msquare - Can you create some data sample, 5-10 rows?

Comment: @bigbounty, In my question above, I have added my actual `for` loop to understand I what I am trying to do. However, thanks for letting me that `lambda` may not be required here but it can be done using `numpy` arrays. Could you elaborate your answer.

Comment: If you want to create a new column, then just do `df['new_column_name'] = df['a'] * df['b']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is each Series is one element with lists, so not possible use vectorized operations.

```
a = pd.Series([list(map(lambda x:x,np.linspace(2,2,new_samples)))],index=['Current'])
b = pd.Series([list(map(lambda x:x,np.linspace(10,0,new_samples)))],index=['Voltage'])

print (a)
Current    [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, ...
dtype: object

print (b)
Voltage    [10.0, 8.88888888888889, 7.777777777777778, 6....
dtype: object
```

So I believe need remove `[]` and if necessary add parameter `name`:

```
a = pd.Series(list(map(lambda x:x,np.linspace(2,2,new_samples))), name='Current')
b = pd.Series(list(map(lambda x:x,np.linspace(10,0,new_samples))),name='Voltage')
print (a)
0    2.0
1    2.0
2    2.0
3    2.0
4    2.0
5    2.0
6    2.0
7    2.0
8    2.0
9    2.0
Name: Current, dtype: float64

print (b)
0    10.000000
1     8.888889
2     7.777778
3     6.666667
4     5.555556
5     4.444444
6     3.333333
7     2.222222
8     1.111111
9     0.000000
Name: Voltage, dtype: float64
```

---

```
c = a * b
print (c)
0    20.000000
1    17.777778
2    15.555556
3    13.333333
4    11.111111
5     8.888889
6     6.666667
7     4.444444
8     2.222222
9     0.000000
dtype: float64
```

EDIT:

If want outoput multiplied Series need last 2 rows:

```
missing_current = pd.Series(list(map(lambda x:x,np.linspace(isc_act,isc_act,new_samples))))
missing_voltage = pd.Series(list(map(lambda x:x,np.linspace(module_allData_df['Voltage'].iloc[isc_indx],0,new_samples))))
print(missing_current *missing_voltage)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easier using `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np
new_samples = 10 # Number of samples in series
a = np.array(np.linspace(2,2,new_samples))
b = np.array(np.linspace(10,0,new_samples))
c = a*b
print(c)
```

Output:

> array([20.        , 17.77777778, 15.55555556, 13.33333333,
>   11.11111111,
>           8.88888889,  6.66666667,  4.44444444,  2.22222222,  0.        ])

As you are doing everything using pandas dataframe, use the below code.

```
import pandas as pd
new_samples = 10 # Number of samples in series
df = pd.DataFrame({'Current':np.linspace(2,2,new_samples),'Voltage':np.linspace(10,0,new_samples)})
df['Power'] = df['Current'] * df['Voltage']
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
Current    Voltage      Power
    2.0  10.000000  20.000000
    2.0   8.888889  17.777778
    2.0   7.777778  15.555556
    2.0   6.666667  13.333333
    2.0   5.555556  11.111111
    2.0   4.444444   8.888889
    2.0   3.333333   6.666667
    2.0   2.222222   4.444444
    2.0   1.111111   2.222222
    2.0   0.000000   0.000000
```

Comment: It looks simple. But, how to assign a name to each list and later append this list to already existing column in a dataframe? Because my dataframe has three columns with some data `df.columns = ['Current','Voltage','Power']`. How to append above arrays `a ('Current')`,`b('Voltage)`,`c('Power')` to these columns?

Comment: Can I put this inside a for loop as shown in above code?

Comment: No, you can't. You are complicating stuff. It's better to learn pandas and python properly before going to this stuff

Answer (score 0):

Because they are series you should be able to just multiply them c= a * b

You could add a and b to a data frame and the c becomes the third column